# Building a data analysis pipeline in R shiny - Caching; Inheritance

Tags: r, caching, shiny, reactive

I am looking for a basic example how to process data inside a shiny app and build a hierarchical structure.

The important thing is, that the data is streamlined through individual steps and only recalculated if variables which affect the underlying structure are processed again.

What I have so far:

in the ui:

`fileInput("file", "Upload file.txt", accept = c("text")),`

in the server logic:

```
data <- reactive({
    req(input$file)
    read.delim(input$file$datapath)
})

observe({
  # first processing step
  processed_data <- processing_stuff(data())
})
```

Now I would like to inherit the processed_data to the next step, plot it, filter it .....

How is it possible to do a stepwise class inheritance?

Thanks in advance

Lukas

Comment: It would be easier not to user `observe`. Use `processed_data <- reactive({processing_stuff(data())})` and then `processed_data` will be just another reactive value and you can use `processed_data()` in further processing steps to get it's current value. Shiny will keep track of the dependencies.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that did the trick. 

unfortunately after several reactive assignments the c stack limit is exceeded.
Is there an efficient way to do that?

Comment: after increasing the c stack limit the following error appears:

evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Comment: If you are reaching the C stack limit that means you have a recursive definition somewhere. There's no recursion in the example you shared so it's unclear what your code is actually doing now. Avoid circular dependencies in your reactive objects.

Comment: The recursive definition is done downstream during analysis. Sorry for the confusion, it`s my first pipeline in R-shiny. 

I changed the code according to your recommendation:

`processed_data <- reactive({
  # first processing step
  processing_stuff(data())
}) `

I am trying to implement several steps, where user can decide which cutoff values to use. e.g.:

`processed_data <- reactive({
  # second processing step
  processing_stuff(data())
}) 


output$plot <- renderPlot({plot(processed_data)}`